# the procedural displacement and bump step

Tags: displacement, procedural, bump

After doing the procedural displacement step, my donut looks dosent look quite right. Does anyone know why that is the case? [image]

I tried to lower down the noise scale and increase the displacement, but it still looks like its curled up rather having bumps.

[image]

Comment: hello, what do you mean by "doesn't look quite right"? maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It just dosent look like the one on the video. Here you go: https://pasteall.org/blend/5ba0a7b5c9dc46bfa755feebb75aa1a1

Comment: seems normal to me, maybe lower down the Noise scale and increase the Displacement scale a bit to see its effect. Note that you have a mesh overlapping, probably what is supposed to be the icing, so it may be the thing that bothers you

Comment: We need to see the details on the Displacement node.  From your pic, I would suspect you're using a displacement scale that's way too high for your geometry.

Comment: It only looks normal to me in material view. But I add a new picture where you can see the noise and displacement scale. I tried to lower down the noise scale and increaste the displacement scala but it didnt quite worked

Comment: Nevermind! I fixed it! I needed to add more subdivision levels

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your donut object does not have enough faces (or subdivision levels). Add some geometry using the subdivide option in edit mode or add a subdivision modifier (or increase the levels if you have one already)

Comment: Yup that was the case! Thanks!